# Does escaping from pursuers in a chase count toward kill streaks?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

So I'm challenge hunting and am working on the Wanted 5-kill streak challenge.  I'd say I'm a Deathmatch veteran and have no trouble picking out my targets and emasculating my pursuers.  Going after targets is not quite as rewarding (nor easy) as taking out pursuers.

But sometimes I end up getting stupid pursuers.  You know the kind, the ones that runs around the map like idiots just looking for a lock indicator to just pop up for them.  It's not worth my time in a lot of cases for me to chase them down just to stun them, often they'd trigger a chase and not know where the heck I am.  So I'd just stay hidden in my blend group as they trot away and get my escape.

Do escapes count toward my kill streaks?  If it does, does it also count for multiple escapes?  i.e., Two pursuers in a chase, one big escape from both of them, two points for the kill streak or one?

I couldn't tell myself whether or not they were adding up as it doesn't happen too often for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant get any count towards your kill streak by escaping.

Stunning and killing are the only ways to get kill-streaks.